# Continuation versus call stack in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghc

How does Haskell (GHC) runtime know what code should be executed next after evaluation of a thunk?

On a conceptual level, how is that different from call stack in other programming languages (other than storing closed variables on heap and having tail recursion)?

Comment: Have you read any of the documentation about how GHC works? The slightly outdated spineless tagless G-machine paper and the GHC Commentary together cover this in significant detail.

Comment: @Daniel, I actually attempted to read them but dropped out. Like many people I learn best by slowly putting together small pieces of information. Reading papers requires a "linear" understanding of all presented concepts, including prerequisities. I believe an answer to this question SO will also help others make step forward in learning Haskell.

Comment: What are you hoping will be done differently in an SO answer here compared to the existing literature? It's a big topic, and "one has to understand the prerequisites" isn't really something that can be changed by writing the answer down a second time.

Comment: I think @sevo has a valid point. Many papers target experts in their field and not practitioners. That's why we have books, tutorials, guides and this Q&A site. However, I agree that getting an understanding of prerequisites is desirable (if time/effort allows this).

Answer (score 2):

GHC (or rather, the GHC RTS) has a normal call stack, like most things.

What's different is the contents of this stack. It doesn't match what you might expect.

Suppose that function `foo` calls function `bar` which calls function `baz`. You *might* be expecting the call stack to look like

```
foo
bar
baz
```

at some point. But actually, when `foo` calls `bar`, all the "call" really does is create a thunk and return instantly. So `bar` doesn't appear on that stack at that point. But when `foo` returns some data to the caller, and the caller decides to do something with it, at that point `bar` may appear on the call stack, even though `foo` is nowhere to be seen.

In short, the order of stuff on the call stack is unrelated to who calls who. It's determined by who looks at what.

Comment: So the code that eventually forces a thunk does so in a similar fashion to C calling convention? Or is it using GHC-specific conventions (and heap-allocated stack) that are otherwise similar in principle?

Comment: I'm a little out of my depth here, but I believe it's something not unlike thiscall. (The thunk evaluation code gets a pointer to the thunk being evaluated. I think there's some other global pointers as an optimisation too.) If you're really interested in this stuff, check out the GHC code commentary.